# Parse issue expected statement C program

Tags: c, xcode

i have an issue when i try to build a code in Xcode
Friends, iam a noobie at C, i need some help

This s my **main.c** file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
       {
       pid_t pid;
       int status;

       if (argc < 2) {
           printf ("Something goes wrong!\n");
           return 1;
       }

    for (;;) {
        pid = fork ();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror ("fork");
            exit (1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            execvp (argv[1], &argv[1]);
        } else {
            wait (&status);
            if (WIFEXITED (status))
            {
                printf ("%s exited with return code %d\n",
                        argv[1], WEXITSTATUS (status));
                if (WEXITSTATUS (status) != 0)
            }
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            {
                printf ("%s terminated by signal number %d\n",
                        argv[1], WTERMSIG (status));
            }
            /* we want to give time to user for read output of program */
            sleep (1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After this line

```
if (WEXITSTATUS (status) != 0)
```

i have a parse issue expected statement
anybody can tell me why its wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: Well, the parser expected a statement and there wasn't one ... If you don't want to do anything add a ; after the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this

```
printf ("%s exited with return code %d\n",
    argv[1], WEXITSTATUS (status));
if (WEXITSTATUS (status) != 0)
```

to this

```
printf ("%s exited with return code %d\n",
    argv[1], WEXITSTATUS (status));
if (WEXITSTATUS (status) != 0);
```

or

```
printf ("%s exited with return code %d\n",
    argv[1], WEXITSTATUS (status));
if (WEXITSTATUS (status) != 0) {}
```